# Android drawing text into bitmap - problems with special characters

Tags: android, canvas, text, paint

I'm having a great deal of difficulty understanding how to render a bullet point into a bitmap.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public Bitmap textIntoBitmap(String text, float textSize) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text));
    int height = (int) (bounds.height());

    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);       
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, bounds.height(), paint);
    return image;
}
```

Now, this should, as far as I'm aware, draw the text aligned to the top of the bitmap.  And this does seem to work for normal letters, so.... so, if my string is 'This is a test'....

[image]

As you can see, the bounds height is 50px, so I create the bitmap using the bounds height, and if I were to draw it at a Y of zero using the canvas.drawText method, it would draw with the bottom edge just at the top of the bitmap like so:

[image]

So therefore, I draw it at bounds height and it sits perfectly within the bitmap like this:

[image]

However, if my string is simply a bullet-point (•), I get some odd results:

[image]

As you can see, the bounds height being returned is 20px (I've taken a screen shot and counted the pixels manually and it is indeed exactly 20 pixels high).

However, if I try to draw it at + bounds height, I get this:

[image]

As you can see if only draws half of the bullet point.  I'm  thinking it's something to do with the fact that the bullet isn't a whole-height character and 'floats' in the middle (vertically) of the space a normal character would take up.  This would explain why I need to add more to the Y that I draw the character at to see more of it. But then again, getTextBounds returns only 20px, the actual size of the visible character and not any blank space, so this seems contradictory.

Would be grateful if someone could explain how to get around this

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set the text in a TextView, something like `&#8729; Some Text` or `\u2219 Some Text`?

Comment: Hi @tRotwang, I'm using this with OpenGL ES 2.0.  What I'm doing is pre-rendering some text strings to a bitmap, applying that bitmap as an OpenGL texture, and then simply grabbing parts of that texture to display phrases as an when needed (as OpenGL ES Quads).  I initially tried using a TextView, but it was clumsy and the performance was lacking.  This does work perfectly (and not to mention allows full control over animation etc) except when using 'non full height' characters (., •, - etc). Cheers

Comment: OK, I trust you. Since I don't know anything about OpenGL ES... ;)